# Create a column for days sampled e.g. 0,10,30 days,starting with 0 days for every study area?

Tags: r, date, tidyr

I like to create some sampling effort curves for species data. Where are several study areas with a number of sampling plots, resampled over a certain time period. My data set looks similar to this one:

```
    df1 <- data.frame(PlotID = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E"),
                  species = c("x","x","x1","x","x1","x2","x1","x3","x4","x4","x5","x5","x","x3","x","x3","x3","x4","x5","x","x1","x2","x3"),
                  date = as.Date(c("27-04-1995",    "26-05-1995",   "02-08-1995",   "02-05-1995",   "28-09-1995",   "02-08-1994",   "31-05-1995",   "27-07-1995",   "06-12-1995",   "03-05-1996",   "27-04-1995",   "31-05-1995",   "29-06-1994",   "30-08-1995",   "26-05-1994",   "30-05-1995",   "30-06-1995",   "30-06-1995",   "30-06-1995",   "30-08-1995",   "31-08-1995",   "01-09-1995","02-09-1995"),'%d-%m-%Y'),
                  area= c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C"))
```

I really would like an output that gives me an extra column of time of sampling e.g. 0, 10 days, 30days for the whole dataframe, but times should start with 0 for each area.  I tried this:

```
effort<-df1%>% arrange(PlotID, date,species) %>% group_by(area) %>%
  mutate(diffDate = difftime(date, lag(date,1))) %>% ungroup()
```

But somehow my code produces nonsense?
Could please somebody enlighten me?

T the end I would like to achieve something like this example below. A List of matrices for every research area with species as rows but not with sampling plots as columns but time (in days, showing the increasing sampling effort). The example shows a data set from the package iNEXT. But I'm stuck with getting the days of sampling calculated for every area between the sampling dates.For now I just want this extra column showing the days between the sampling events in each area and the species found. I hope now it's a bit clearer?
[image]

Edit: This is how the date in my real data set looks like:

```
output from dput(head(my.data))
date= structure(c(801878400, 798940800, 780710400, 769910400, 775785600, 798940800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")
```

Comment: Hi, you want the first sample in area "A" to be 0 and the second the difference of days elapsed since the first sampling in this area, right?

Comment: it is not very clear of what you want to accomplish. The diffDate in your effort should be the difference between current and previous sample (grouped by area only?) or current and first sample (group by area?), may you can write a mock data frame with the desired results.

Comment: Can you show expected output for the data shared?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I just updated my question. @Pedro Alencar all the plots in each areas should be sampled at the same day at each sampling event. So yes the first sampling date in each area should be 0 and every following date should be shown in days passed since the start date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible `tidyverse` solution would be

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% arrange(area, date) %>% 
  group_by(area)  %>% 
  mutate(diff_date_from_start = date - min(date), 
         diff_date_from_prev = date - lag(date))
#> # A tibble: 23 x 6
#> # Groups:   area [3]
#>    PlotID species date       area  diff_date_from_start diff_date_from_prev
#>    <chr>  <chr>   <date>     <chr> <drtn>               <drtn>             
#>  1 B      x2      1994-08-02 A       0 days              NA days           
#>  2 A      x       1995-04-27 A     268 days             268 days           
#>  3 A      x       1995-05-02 A     273 days               5 days           
#>  4 A      x       1995-05-26 A     297 days              24 days           
#>  5 B      x1      1995-05-31 A     302 days               5 days           
#>  6 B      x3      1995-07-27 A     359 days              57 days           
#>  7 A      x1      1995-08-02 A     365 days               6 days           
#>  8 A      x1      1995-09-28 A     422 days              57 days           
#>  9 B      x4      1995-12-06 A     491 days              69 days           
#> 10 B      x4      1996-05-03 A     640 days             149 days           
#> # … with 13 more rows
```

- The `diff_date_from_prev` variable might make more sense if you group by other variables as well, such as `species` and `PlotID`.
- The `diff_date_from_prev` calculates the difference in days between the current sample and the first sample in for each Area.

### Edit to answer comment:

Your `date` is stored as POSIX and not as Date class. If time zones are not relevant, I find easier to work with `Date`, so one option is converting to Date `as.Date()` and then applying the manipulations as stated previously. Alternatively you can use the `difftime()` function as suggested by @Rui Barradas in the comments and specify the unit accordingly.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(PlotID = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C","D","D","D","D","D","E","E","E"),
                  species = c("x","x","x1","x","x1","x2","x1","x3","x4","x4","x5","x5","x","x3","x","x3","x3","x4","x5","x","x1","x2","x3"),
                  # date as posix not as date. they are different data classs.  
                  date = as.POSIXct(c("27-04-1995",    "26-05-1995",   "02-08-1995",   "02-05-1995",   "28-09-1995",   "02-08-1994",   "31-05-1995",   "27-07-1995",   "06-12-1995",   "03-05-1996",   "27-04-1995",   "31-05-1995",   "29-06-1994",   "30-08-1995",   "26-05-1994",   "30-05-1995",   "30-06-1995",   "30-06-1995",   "30-06-1995",   "30-08-1995",   "31-08-1995",   "01-09-1995","02-09-1995"),'%d-%m-%Y'),
                  area= c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C"))


library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df1 %>% arrange(area, date) %>% 
  group_by(area)  %>% 
  mutate(
    date = as.Date(date),
    diff_date_from_start = date - min(date)
  )
#> # A tibble: 23 x 6
#> # Groups:   area [3]
#>    PlotID species date       area  diff_date_from_start diff_date_time
#>    <chr>  <chr>   <date>     <chr> <drtn>               <drtn>        
#>  1 A      x       2-05-19    A         0 days               0 days    
#>  2 A      x1      2-08-19    A        92 days              92 days    
#>  3 B      x2      2-08-19    A        92 days              92 days    
#>  4 B      x4      3-05-19    A       365 days             365 days    
#>  5 B      x4      6-12-19    A      1675 days            1675 days    
#>  6 A      x       26-05-19   A      8766 days            8766 days    
#>  7 A      x       27-04-19   A      9101 days            9101 days    
#>  8 B      x3      27-07-19   A      9192 days            9192 days    
#>  9 A      x1      28-09-19   A      9620 days            9620 days    
#> 10 B      x1      31-05-19   A     10592 days           10592 days    
#> # … with 13 more rows
```

```r
# or as suggested by Rui Barradas. you can use difftime function and keep you date as a POSIX class
df1 %>% arrange(area, date) %>% 
  group_by(area)  %>% 
  mutate(
    diff_date_time = difftime(date, min(date), unit = "days")
  )
#> # A tibble: 23 x 5
#> # Groups:   area [3]
#>    PlotID species date                area  diff_date_time
#>    <chr>  <chr>   <dttm>              <chr> <drtn>        
#>  1 A      x       2-05-19 00:00:00    A         0 days    
#>  2 A      x1      2-08-19 00:00:00    A        92 days    
#>  3 B      x2      2-08-19 00:00:00    A        92 days    
#>  4 B      x4      3-05-19 00:00:00    A       365 days    
#>  5 B      x4      6-12-19 00:00:00    A      1675 days    
#>  6 A      x       26-05-19 00:00:00   A      8766 days    
#>  7 A      x       27-04-19 00:00:00   A      9101 days    
#>  8 B      x3      27-07-19 00:00:00   A      9192 days    
#>  9 A      x1      28-09-19 00:00:00   A      9620 days    
#> 10 B      x1      31-05-19 00:00:00   A     10592 days    
#> # … with 13 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. Not sure what's going on, but with my real data set I'm only getting the diff_date_from_ columns in seconds? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I believe it might be the data type of `date` might be different in your dataset. Please provide the output of `dput(YOUR_DATA)`. if YOUR_DATA is too big, `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` should be enough. With that we can see exactly how your data really looks like. Append the result at the end of your question. (and comment here so I get a notification)

Comment: @MarceloAvila To get the diff times in days, try `difftime(date, min(date), unit = "days")` and the same for `lag(date)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help @MarceloAvila - I updated my question so that you can see how my date is formated in my real data set.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a `for` loop

```
areas <- unique(df1$area)

df1$diffdate <- 0
for (i in 1:length(areas)){
  df1$diffdate[df1$area == areas[i]] <- df1$date[df1$area == areas[i]] - min(df1$date[df1$area == areas[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a sequence of dates by 10 days for each group of `area`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  arrange(PlotID, date, species) %>% 
  group_by(area) %>%
  complete(date = full_seq(date, 1)) %>%
  mutate(species = zoo::na.locf(species),
         PlotID = zoo::na.locf(PlotID),
         diffDate = 10*as.integer(date - first(date)) %/% 10) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(diffDate) %>%
  filter(row_number() == 1)
## A tibble: 65 x 5
## Groups:   diffDate [65]
#   area  date       PlotID species diffDate
#   <chr> <date>     <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>
# 1 A     1994-08-02 B      x2             0
# 2 A     1994-08-12 B      x2            10
# 3 A     1994-08-22 B      x2            20
# 4 A     1994-09-01 B      x2            30
# 5 A     1994-09-11 B      x2            40
# 6 A     1994-09-21 B      x2            50
# 7 A     1994-10-01 B      x2            60
# 8 A     1994-10-11 B      x2            70
# 9 A     1994-10-21 B      x2            80
#10 A     1994-10-31 B      x2            90
## … with 55 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks - but I would like to use the real differences in days between the consecutive sampling dates not a 10 days sequence...

Comment: @Conny Like in [Marcelo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67948427/8245406)? If not, what is it in it that doesn't answer the question?

Comment: I'm currently trying to get Marcelo's code to work with my real data set, but all times that I get are in seconds? Not sure what's going on, might be an issue with the date format.So not sure yet, if it works the way it should.